# Hightchart: Doing drilldown with columrange

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, highcharts

I am trying to create a columnrange chart with a drilldown. I saw many examples with simple values (as y:10.2) but I would like to try with more complexe data as y:[5,10] in the way to create a drilldown based on columnrange.Here is a pieace of code to give you an idea of what I am trying to do:

```
data = [{
                y: 19,
                color: colors[0],
                drilldown: {
                    name: 'MSIE versions',
                    categories: ['Amount', 'Duration', 'Age'],
                    data: [{
                            y: [7.35,10.85],
                            color: colors[0],
                            drilldown: {
                                name: 'MSIE versions',
                                categories: ['Amount', 'Duration', 'Age'],
                                data: [[7.35,10.85], [2.81,33.06]],
                                color: colors[0]
                            }
                        }, {
                            y: [0.32,9.91],
                            color: colors[1],
                            drilldown: {
                                name: 'Firefox versions',
                                categories: ['Amount', 'Duration', 'Age'],
                                data: [[0.20,0.83], [5.43,13.12], [0.32,9.91]],
                                color: colors[1]
                            }
                        }, {
                            y: [5.43,13.12],
                            color: colors[2],
                            drilldown: {
                                name: 'Chrome versions',
                                categories: ['Amount', 'Duration', 'Age'],
                                data: [[0.12,0.19], [0.12,0.36], [0.32,9.91]],
                                color: colors[2]
                            }
                        }],
                    color: colors[0]
                }
            },........................//it continues like this but you got the idea
```

I have a [JSFiddl](http://jsfiddle.net/goontor/bs3bn/) in the way to show you what I want exactly. If you look at it you will see that my categories apear but my columns are not build. Is it impossible to do such a thing with Hightchart?If it is possible then please let me know how to do it :)

Thx guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to use `y` as array, while you should use `low` and `high`.

So in short, change all:

```
y: [7.35,10.85],
```

to:

```
low: 7.35,
high: 10.85,
```